# Getting last x and y coordinates of ACTION_UP android

Tags: android, touch-event, motionevent

i would like to know how to get the last X and Y coordinate value of the ACTION_UP motion event, since this motion event returns the last release point as well as any intermediate points since the last down event. I would like to uniquely store the last X and Y coordinates (the last x and y before the user releases his finger)

Answer (score 0):

Use `MotionEvent#getX()` and `MotionEvent#getY()` to extract the most recent coordinates.

Comment: Using getx() and gety() in ACTION_UP not only gets the last release point but also intermediate points between the last down event as i said above, i only need the last x and y coordinates before the finger is lifted

Answer (score 0):

Check `motionEvent.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE` and get last coordinates before `MotionEvent.ACTION_UP`